# Data base information in INI file

Tags: php, mysql

For my school project I need to recover some information one database and associate with another database. But for that I want to use a ini file because if the log for connection of one data base change, I don't want to change it in the code.

My code is :

```
<?php
// On recupére les info dans fichier ini pour mySQL
//Get Information in ini for mySQL

$fichier = 'BDDconnexion.ini';

if(file_exists($fichier)){

$config = parse_ini_file($fichier,true);

$ip = "$config['mySQL'][ip]";
$port = "$config['mySQL'][port]";
$nomBDD = "config['mySQL'][nomBDD]";
$login = "$config['mySQL'][login]";
$password = "$config['mySQL'][password]";


}

// On se connecte à MySQL
//Connexion to MySQL
try {
$bdd = new PDO(mysql . ':host='.$ip.'dbname='.$nomBDD,$login,$password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE =>  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    } 
catch (Exception $e) 
    {
     die('Erreur : '. $e->getMessage());
    }


?>
```

It is not working and i have this error message :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\connectmySQL.php on line 14.

And the composition of my ini file is :

```
[mySQL]
ip="127.0.0.1"
port=4900
nomBDD=MagicCash
login="******"
password=""
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic PHP: You cannot have quoted array keys in a `"`-quoted string:

```
$ip = "$config['mySQL'][ip]";
               ^-----^--- incorrect
```

The following are proper syntax for such things:

```
$ip = "foo $arr[key] bar";
$ip = "foo {$arr['key']} bar"; // note the {}
$Ip = "foo " . $arr['key'] . " bar";
```

Also note that you're using a multidimensional array, which will also cause problems. PHP's parser is not greedy:

```
$foo['bar']['baz'] = 'qux';
echo "$foo[bar][baz]"; // output is "Array[baz]"
```

For multi-dimensional array variables in a `"`-quoted string, you **MUST** use the `{}` notation:

```
echo "{$foo['bar']['baz']}"; // outputs 'qux'
```

And of course, in the greater scheme, your variables don't need to be quoted AT ALL. These two statements

```
$foo = "$bar";
$foo = $bar;
```

are essentially functionally identical, except the `"$bar"` version forces PHP to create a new string, fill in the `$bar` value, then assign it to $foo. Sometimes this is desired if `$bar` is something OTHER than a string, but generally it's a waste of cpu cycles.

Comment: So for my code work I need to change this line : $ip = "$config['mySQL'][ip]"; with that ? $ip = "foo $arr[ip] bar"; I don't understand what is "foo" "arr" and "bar", i'm not good at all for the moment in this..

Comment: So I can write :

$ip = "foo $config[mySQL][ip] bar";

for find the setting of my IP that I need for my connection in mySQL?

Comment: no, you just need `$ip = $config['mySQL']['ip']`